# Custom UIButton class does not show title

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I have created a custom `UIButton` class.  But the title does not show up. I only get the background color and the rounded corners. But the title is not visible.

Also when I run it in simulator, iOS 13+, its showing the title white. But when I run in my device i.e. iOS 12.4, its not working.

Here is my code:

```
public class CornerButton : UIButton {

    public override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setup()
        self.layoutIfNeeded()

    }

    public required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setup()
        self.layoutIfNeeded()

    }

    func setup() {
        self.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Poppins-SemiBold", size: 12)
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor(named: "BarColor")
        self.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal) // this line is not working
        self.clipsToBounds = true

    }

    public override func layoutSubviews() {
        self.roundCorners(corners: [.topRight,.bottomLeft], radius: 10)
    }

}
```

Comment: share the usages of the button `CornerButton` !

Comment: @Vicky_Vignesh I have the button in the storyboard. I assigned it this custom class. Everything is working fine. Just the title not showing.

Comment: suspect this line `self.roundCorners(corners: [.topRight,.bottomLeft], radius: 10)` comment it and try

Comment: @Sh_Khan it worked. I removed the line from `layoutSubviews()` and placed it at first line in `setup()`.

Comment: should i add it as answer or fly

Comment: @Sh_Khan please add.

Comment: before that can you try it as it's with adding `super.layoutSubviews()` ?? and tell

Comment: @Sh_Khan that's working too .. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `super.layoutSubviews()`

```
public override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    self.roundCorners(corners: [.topRight,.bottomLeft], radius: 10)
}
```

BTW here you don't need `layoutSubviews` as you use it when you need to make something that depends on the actual measured bounds of the view and as you set a static radius you can omit it

Comment: The button is in storyboard. and it has the title